# Adding Threat Intel fields in Elasticsearch data

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-beats

How we can add threat intel data for elastic agent logs before they are entering into the Elasticsearch cluster?

I am trying to add some new fields to each log before based on the details present in that logs.

Example: If you consider VirusTotal

Based on the process name collected by our elastic agent I need to add one more field in each row by calculating its Virustotal score.

How we can add that additional field?

Comment: how do you go about calculating the score?

Comment: I have a third party agent which can provide these details

Comment: can you put that data into an index?

Comment: yes I am able to put that data into my index

Comment: if you can put it into another index, then look at using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/enrich-processor.html